# How to get progress while uploading file to azure blob storage using Browser method

Tags: javascript, azure, progress-bar, azure-blob-storage

When I am trying to upload files to my blob storage I am always getting progress percentage as 0 or 100.
(There is no problem in uploading, Files are uploading accurately to my storage. The only problem is with progress percentage)

Here is my render code which calls uploadFiles Method

```
    render(){
        if(this.props.files.length > 0)
            this.uploadFiles(this.props.files);
        return (<div></div>);
    }
```

Here is the uploadFiles Method

```
uploadFiles = (files) => {
        var accountName = this.props.accountName;
        var SasToken = this.props.sasToken;
        var blobUri = 'https://' + accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
        var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas (blobUri, SasToken);
        var containerName = 'my-blob';
        Array.from(files).forEach(file => {
            var customBlockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 * 512;
            blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = customBlockSize;
            var finishedOrError = false;
            var speedSummary = blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile(containerName, file.name, file, {blockSize : customBlockSize},(error, result, response) => {
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                } else {
                    console.log(result);
                    finishedOrError = true;
                    console.log(response);
                }            


            })  
    /*Here when I tried to console, I am always getting process variable value as zero which is declared in refreshProgress() method*/
            function refreshProgress() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!finishedOrError) {
                        var process = speedSummary.getCompletePercent();
                        console.log('entered',process);
                        refreshProgress();
                    }
                }, 300);
            }

          refreshProgress();

        });
    }
```

I referred this one https://dmrelease.blob.core.windows.net/azurestoragejssample/samples/sample-blob.html for uploading the file to azure. But the progress part is not clear to me.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`speedSummary`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/66d24e89eeedf77ab83356c69fe5a39ed03b73b9/lib/common/streams/speedsummary.js), you will notice that it extends `EventEmitter` and it emits `progress` event. All you need to do is subscribe to this event in your code and call the methods to get the progress.

For example, here's pseudo code (not tested):

```
speedSummary.on('progress', function() {
  var percentComplete = speedSummary.getCompletePercent(2);
  console.log('Upload Complete (%): ' + percentComplete);
});
```